# IPtables log only some drop connections

Tags: iptables, logging, syslog, rsyslog

I have these rules:

```
-A INPUT -m limit --limit 2/min -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables Packet Dropped: " --log-level 7
-A INPUT -j DROP
```

But this logs every DROP that occurs like `IPTables Packet Dropped: IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=XXXXXXXX SRC=192.168.100.11 DST=192.168.100.255`.

I want to log only when DST is `192.168.100.19`.

Comment: @MadHatter i tried what i have above (on question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to insert a rule for the IP you want to log before the catch all rule you have.

```
iptables -A INPUT -d 192.168.100.19 -m limit --limit 2/min -j LOG --log-prefix "IPTables Packet Dropped: " --log-level 7
```